# Running one OS per core

Tags: ubuntu, multi-core

I'm interested in using a COTS board like the [Wandboard](http://www.wandboard.org/) for a project. On one hand I'd like to use something like Ubuntu for user interaction, sounds, TCP/IP stuff, etc. But I also need an RTOS like uC/OS-II since there are some real-time requirements. Are there any resources to help set up something like this?

I've only used multi-core processors with a single kernel before (SMP), so this is new to me. Apparently, [this guy](http://blog.csdn.net/samssm/article/details/8720600) has done it, but I can find information only sparingly.